# How to hide a view of recycler view in a single fragment in android (But using same list in two fragments)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I am using a recycler view in two fragments.

But one of the fragments needs not to show a particular view. But Need to show all the views in another screen.

How can I hide that particular view alone in one of my fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_radius"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white_new"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/Divider.Horizontal.Gray" android:id="@+id/divider"  android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use a viewmodel scoped to the activity and based on the fragments currently shown, take the required action

Comment: Can you give any samples

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use if condition for this or

```
yourAdapter(isoneFramgent:Boolean){

}
```

send true and false from your fragment if its from first fragment send true and its from second fragment send false and add a if condition into bindView to show and hide your view according to fragment

Comment: How can I show only two items in a fragment and all items in another fragment

Comment: use this in bind view
if (isoneFragment==true){
//hide all the other item and show inly two}else{
//showAllItem here }

Answer (score 0):

Filter your data source before setting it to `adapter` and pass the filtered data to one `fragment` and raw data to other fragment.

Suppose you have list of strings

```
val originalData = listOf("data") //this is your raw list
//Fragment 1
  val f1Data = ArrayList(originalData.filter{ //filter one item })
  val f1Adapter = YourAdapter(f1Data)
//Fragment 2
  val f2Adapter = YourAdapter(originalData)
```

Comment: I need to hide the view only . Can you let me know why the filter need here <View style="@style/Divider.Horizontal.Gray" android:id="@+id/divider"  android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>.